# Error: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous when splitting strings into two columns if two conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, boolean-logic

I am trying to make split the string in column['first'] if the following two conditions are met.

1. column['first'] contains words 'floor' or 'floors'
2. column['second'] is empty

However, I received an error message.

**The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Below is my code

```
#boolean series for condition 1: when values in column['second'] are empty

only_first_token = pd.isna(results_threshold_50_split_ownership['second']) 
print (len(only_first_token)) 
print (type(only_first_token))

#boolean series for condition 2: when values in column['first'] contain string floor or floors

first_token_contain_floor = results_threshold_50_split_ownership['first'].str.contains('floors|floor',case=False)
print (len(first_token_contain_floor))
print (type(only_first_token))

#if both conditions are met, the string in column['first'] will be split into column['first'] and['second']

if results_threshold_50_split_ownership[(only_first_token) & (first_token_contain_floor)]:
    results_threshold_50_split_ownership.first.str.split('Floors|Floor', expand=True)

print(results_threshold_50_split_ownership['first'])
```

I have read some answers here and have already changed the code a few times. I made sure the total number of boolean are the same at 1016. And I can successfully locate the rows that can fulfil the two conditions with the same code if I remove `if`. So I don't understand why it is ambiguous.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Please post the traceback so we an see the line and error together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are perfectly OK, the problem is the if statement - it reads:

```
if boolean_array :
  ...
```

but `if` needs just **one** boolean value, **not a whole array** of booleans. In order to reduce a boolean array to just one value you can use e.g. any() or all() as the error message suggests -  `if all(boolean_array):` etc.

What you really want to do is probably:

```
results_threshold_50_split_ownership[(only_first_token) & (first_token_contain_floor)]['first'].str.split('Floors|Floor', expand=True)
```

i.e. use the boolean array for boolean indexing.

**Update as per comment below:**
You can assign the result of the splitting to the orginal columns using `results_threshold_50_split_ownership.loc[(only_first_token) & (first_token_contain_floor), ['first', 'second']]`. In this can you need to make sure, however, that maximum 2 columns are being return by specifying `n=1` in the split function (in case your fist column contains the word 'floor' multiple times).
Example:

```
results_threshold_50_split_ownership = pd.DataFrame({'first': ['first floor value', 'all floors values', 'x'],
                                                     'second': ['y', None, None]})
print(results_threshold_50_split_ownership)
#               first second
#0  first floor value      y
#1  all floors values   None
#2                  x   None
only_first_token = pd.isna(results_threshold_50_split_ownership['second'])
first_token_contain_floor = results_threshold_50_split_ownership['first'].str.contains('floors|floor',case=False)
results_threshold_50_split_ownership.loc[(only_first_token) & (first_token_contain_floor), ['first', 'second']] = results_threshold_50_split_ownership[(only_first_token) & (first_token_contain_floor)]['first'].str.split('floors|floor', 1, expand=True).to_numpy()
print(results_threshold_50_split_ownership)
#               first   second
#0  first floor value        y
#1               all    values
#2                  x     None
```

Comment: Thank you, @Stef! Your code helps. I then used `join` function so that the concerned strings are split into two separate new columns of the existing data frame. I am wondering if there is any way that I can replace the existing values of those rows, which match the conditions, in the **existing**columns of the data frame i.e` first` and `second`?

Comment: Please see my updated answer (hope I understood you correctly, if not please provide the desired output).

Comment: you are a star! Thank you, Stef!